# ¿Como puedo recorrer una cola en java?

Tags: java, lista

Estoy intentando recorrer una lista Queue en java.
he creado un método para recorrer la cola que se llama 
recorrerEspera().
 Estoy usando eclipse por lo que intente esto: listaEspera.peek().get(i), pero no me reconoce  el metodo get(i).

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

public class ColeccionVehEspera {
    Queue<Vehiculo> listaEspera;//= new Queue<Vehiculo>();

    public ColeccionVehEspera() {

        this.listaEspera = new Queue<Vehiculo>() {

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Vehiculo> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<Vehiculo> iterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean remove(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean add(Vehiculo e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Vehiculo element() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean offer(Vehiculo e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Vehiculo peek() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Vehiculo poll() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Vehiculo remove() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
    }



    public void recorrerEspera()  {

        for (int i = 0; i < listaEspera.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listaEspera.peek());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementarla como una lista ligada,  para poder recorrerla, lo que tú haces no funciona porque en tu caso `peek()` devuelve un Vehiculo el cual no tiene el método `get()`, aparte de que no definiste una implementación de ese método para tu cola.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

    public class ColeccionVehEspera {
    Queue<Vehiculo> listaEspera = new LinkedList<Vehiculo>();

    public ColeccionVehEspera(){
      listaEspera.add(new Vehiculo());
      listaEspera.add(new Vehiculo());
    }

    public void recorrerEspera()  {
      for(Vehiculo v: listaEspera){
        System.out.println(v.toString());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: El método toString() debe estar sobreescrito en tu clase vehículo para que muestre las propiedades de tu clase, de otra forma sólo va a imprimir números.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda voy a ver si lo termino de entender..    Yo pensaba que estaba bien declarado por que no me daba ningun error: this.listaEspera = new Queue<Vehiculo>()

Comment: Por otro lado aparte de la implementación debí usar new LinkedList en vez de new Queue??

Comment: En realidad hay más implementaciones que pudiste usar, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html en este enlace en la parte de "All know implementing classes" puedes encontrar todas las implementaciones que se pueden usar para Quehue.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que Quehue es una interfaz, las interfaces sólo definen comportamiento pero no tienen una implementación.